# pycharm step over shortcut on Mac

Tags: macos, pycharm, shortcut

I'm on Mac with Pycharm. During debug, when I press <kbd>F8</kbd> for step over shortcut, I actually triggers iTunes because <kbd>F8</kbd> is for play/Stop music by default. Any idea what shortkey I can use for step over?

Comment: You need to press `Fn` and `F8` to trigger the function key, and not the shortcut function (which plays music).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

mmm, 2 options, you can go to settings in mac and go to keybpard,

> unchek use F1, F2 ,etc, as standar functions keys

the another options is that sometimes you can press <kbd>FN</kbd> key and then the <kbd>F8</kbd> key, and see what happens...