# Assign F8 to Debug Step Into shortcut in Mac VBE

Tags: excel, vba, macos

Like [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38690874/pycharm-step-over-shortcut-on-mac) and [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39685723/using-shortcuts-in-mac-for-debugging) I too would like to use the `F8` key to step through code when dubugging Excel VBA projects on the Mac (this is done in Windows without problem). But `F8` is assigned to iTunes, and the shortcut `cmd-shift-I` is awkward, requiring 2 hands.

I can re-assign it using the System Settings (as shown in the image below) but even though it looks like it's been reassigned, the `F8` key still doesn't work to step through code (but `cmd-shift-I` still works).

[image]

[image]

The other posts 'solutions' to this problem do not work for me. (Namely, using the function key FN-F8 or checking the "Use F1,F2,etc. keys as standard function keys" within Settings.)

Comment: Not a Mac user... But can't you fn-lock? Or change the iTunes shortcut?

Comment: As far as I know, "no".  That's the point of my question.

Comment: I can check it when I get back home but I hope you are aware that in the new macbook pro there are no fuctions keys. it has been replaced with a touch panel. To access the function keys temporarily, one has to press the fn key and then the relevant key. So even if you managed to set F8, you will still have to use two keys (2 hands) :D

Comment: Unless you set them permanently as show [here](https://www.imore.com/how-make-function-keys-default-touch-bar-display)

Comment: I'm using an external (mac) keyboard purchased in 2019 on a MacBook pro without a touch panel. I'm aware of the FN key (as shown in my post) and even have special software (Palua) to make switching FN modes easier. Just want an answer if you have one -- thanks

Answer (score 0):

Give this a shot, it worked for me.

1. Install Karabiner-Elements
2. Add a Complex Modification Rule - Use the import from Internet button
3. In search box on the web type "F2" and search. Then import the "F2 to cut, F3 to copy, F4 to paste" json file
4. Open finder and navigate to: ~/.config/karabiner/assets/complex_modifications
5. edit the .json file and replace contents with the code below
6. save file, then enable the rule in the karabiner app.

   ```
   {
       "title": "F8 to Command Shift i",
       "rules": [
           {
               "description": "F8 to Command Shift i",
               "manipulators": [
                   {
                       "from": {
                           "key_code": "f8",
                       },
                       "to": [
                           {
                               "key_code": "i",
                               "modifiers": [
                                   "command",
                                   "left_shift"
                               ]
                           }
                       ],
                       "type": "basic"
                   }
               ]
           },
       ]
   }
   ```

Comment: I tried this but it didn't work for me. Installing was easy, installing and editing the .json file wasn't hard, granting all the different system permissions (3 of them, I think) was a little more tricky. It then asked me to restart the app. But, when I tried F8 within the Excel Macro editor it still brought up the Music player. I tried using the "EvenViewer" but that didn't help. So at that point I gave up and am now wondering how to uninstall?